# More than one parent in the RPL protcol

Tags: iot, contiki, cooja, contiki-ng

Does Contiki-NG support more than one parent in the RPL implementation? If yes how I can enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not such support in the mainline Contiki-NG or Contiki.

But it would not be too difficult to add in terms of editing the code, and there have been a few research papers that have experimented with this. Some of them may even have implementations available.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please introduce one of the related papers?